# Xcode Device Logs both type and process are Unknown

Tags: objective-c, xcode

What does it means Xcode Device Logs both are Process and Type unknown? My App is crashing but the only report I get is:

```
Incident Identifier: 33E3CEF3-C2A2-4F21-BEB4-56FC9A20AB62
CrashReporter Key:   c51879d0d5337cafa9240e2d296c1239048a4713
Hardware Model:      iPad3,1
OS Version:          iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 11.0.0: Sun Apr  8 21:52:26 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1878.11.10~1/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8945X
Date:                2012-12-27 12:11:39 -0300
Time since snapshot: 338 ms

Free pages:        7710
Active pages:      32586
Inactive pages:    19459
Throttled pages:   138248
Purgeable pages:   710
Wired pages:       51955
Largest process:   ukingdom

Processes
         Name                 UUID                    Count resident pages
     pasteboardd <6b71e15d2fe432639d1c8e127a8ede10>     256
        ukingdom <253fa43b568539b49cae65641094284f>  131217 (jettisoned) (active)
     debugserver <2408bf4540f63c55b656243d522df7b2>     316
       gputoolsd <8cd5bb538e623da98b5e85c85bd02a91>     705
      MobileMail <eed7992f4c1d3050a7fb5d04f1534030>    2094 (jettisoned)
     MobilePhone <8f3f3e982d9235acbff1e33881b0eb13>    1661 (jettisoned)
springboardservi <b74f5f58317031e9aef7e95744c816ca>     614
             atc <1e5f2a595709376b97f7f0fa29368ef1>    1849
notification_pro <373a488638c436b48ef0801b212593c4>     173
notification_pro <373a488638c436b48ef0801b212593c4>     157
notification_pro <373a488638c436b48ef0801b212593c4>     177
    syslog_relay <b07876a121a432d39d89daf531e8f2bd>     134
notification_pro <373a488638c436b48ef0801b212593c4>     173
            afcd <c3cc9d594b523fd1902fb69add11c25d>     241
            ptpd <62bc5573db7a352ab68409e87dc9abb9>    1153
        networkd <80ba40030462385085b5b7e47601d48d>     268
      aosnotifyd <8cf4ef51f0c635dc920be1d4ad81b322>     829
        BTServer <31e82dfa7ccd364fb8fcc650f6194790>     561
      aggregated <a12fa71e6997362c83e0c23d8b4eb5b7>     547
            apsd <e7a29f2034083510b5439c0fb5de7ef1>     458
            awdd <67774945965531e98d98c2e23a230526>     398
     dataaccessd <473ff40f3bfd3f71b5e3b4335b2011ee>    1341
    fairplayd.J1 <3884d48fa4393c73aa8b3febf95ca258>    1065
       fseventsd <914b28fa8f8a362fabcc47294380c81c>     571
            iapd <0a747292a113307abb17216274976be5>     741
         imagent <9c3a4f75d1303349a53fc6555ea25cd7>     544
       locationd <cf31b0cddd2d3791a2bfcd6033c99045>     897
   mDNSResponder <86ccd4633a6c3c7caf44f51ce4aca96d>     388
    mediaremoted <327f00bfc10b3820b4a74b9666b0c758>     370
    mediaserverd <f03b746f09293fd39a6079c135e7ed00>    1398
           wifid <3001cd0a61fe357d95f170247e5458f5>     512
          powerd <133b7397f5603cf8bef209d4172d6c39>     268
       lockdownd <b06de06b9f6939d3afc607b968841ab9>     542
CommCenterClassi <041d4491826e3c6b911943eddf6aaac9>     473
     SpringBoard <c74dc89dec1c3392b3f7ac891869644a>   13198 (active)
         configd <ee72b01d85c33a24b3548fa40fbe519c>     540
         syslogd <7153b590e0353520a19b74a14654eaaa>     289
         notifyd <f6a9aa19d33c3962aad3a77571017958>     255
  UserEventAgent <dc32e6824fd33bf189b266102751314f>     605
         launchd <5fec01c378a030a8bd23062689abb07f>     274

**End**
```

Using Xcode 4.6 and it happens with many different devices with different IOS versions
Thanks

Comment: No, Simulator never gets the crash. In real device only. I'm going to run Zombie to check if it happens

Comment: You can debug on the device.

Comment: Here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html it says if you see next to your app name 'jettisoned' it means your app was terminated to free up memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The report you added doesn't tell that much. It just shows the processes you have enabled at the time of the crash. 
What you could do try these two things:

1. Try to replicate the crash when debugging on the device, as user dashdom told you: enable zombie
2. Enable "logging" under `Settings` > `Developer` and connect the device to Xcode while running the app normally. The use the organizer (⌘ + ⇧ + 2) go to `Devices` > `(Your device)` > `Console` and see if anything pops up in the console. That could give you more of an idea on what happens.

Hope that helped.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. It's related to memory issues so now I'm running Instruments in the device

Comment: Good! You *can* attach to a process when running the app separately.